# react-native fetch throws "Network request failed" error on Android Devices with backend in http remote server

Tags: android, react-native

i used node js as a backend in a remote server(not localhost) with "188.226.146.190:3000/api/meetups", but i got network error in android 5.1 physical devise and return undefined as output of api,what should i do? i used a simple get requset to my api. i test an example api "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users" and it works properly with this test api.
i have an api file:

```
    export const fetchMeetups = () => 
        fetch('http://188.226.146.190:3000/api/meetups')
                .then(res => res.json()).catch((e) =>e);
```

and in the app.js:

```
static defaultProps = {
    fetchMeetups
}
state = {
    loading: false,
    meetups: []
}

async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        loading: true
    });
    const data = await this.props.fetchMeetups();
    setTimeout( () => this.setState({loading: false, meetups: 
    data.meetups}),2000);
}
```

and in the android i got this error:
Network request failed

Comment: Share some code. It is difficult to help if we cant see how it looks like

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca i add code

Comment: Maybe your device wants it to be HTTPS? It's typically a problem of iOS platform, but who knows...

Comment: Do you get that error in the fetchMeetups.catch? How does data look like?

Comment: i got error in my android phone, but when i use https api, it works properly@FacundoLaRocca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network request failed normally means the the server was not reachable.

To get more information about failures like this you can add Stetho to your project. It allows you to see failures in the network tab of your browsers and examine them like you would do in the tests.

The React Native docs have a detailed section about this at [debugging#debugging-with-stetog](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#debugging-with-stetho-http-facebook-github-io-stetho-on-android).

In your case I would assume that the IP of your service is not up-to-date anymore, you might want to check this.

Comment: what do you mean by that "the ip of your service is not up-to-date anymore"? the api works properly in the browsers.

Comment: @MasihFathi okay, then never mind about that part of the answer

Comment: as you say, the ip has problem, i set a domain for the ip and then used ssl for the domain and then problem solved.